# Javascript/appcelerator - not able to detect XML

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to use a framework called appcelerator titanium to make a simple iphone app. I'm trying to bring in an XML source and simply test its length, but nothing is being returned (and no errors are being thrown). I can't figure out what's going on. If I swap this XML URL out:

http://superfad.com/work/rss

for, say, this one:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Superfad

I can find the length just fine, so I'm guessing it's either some sort of crossdomain issue, or malformed XML, or something. Here's my code:

```
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    // Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
    //loader.open("GET","http://superfad.com/json/featured");
    //loader.open("GET","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Superfad");
    loader.open("GET","http://superfad.com/work/rss");
    //loader.open("GET","test.xml");
    // Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
    loader.onload = function() 
    {
        Ti.API.log('projects!'); //THIS WORKS
        var projects = eval('('+this.responseText+')');
        Ti.API.debug('length' + projects.length) //THIS DOES NOT

    };
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to evaluate the xml of the rss feed as json.  Your first link returns xml, your second links returns json.  `eval` will work on json but not xml.  As a note, don't use `eval` to parse json. use `JSON.parse`.